# Why null value counts are different in pandas and sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, python-3.x, pandas

I was comparing null values in pandas and sql. But, for a single column, both values are not same. There are not null values for sql but there are for pandas. I tried both `.isnull()` and `.isna()` but result did not change.

```
df_contacts.isna().sum()[df_contacts.isna().sum()>0].plot(kind='bar')
# or
df_contacts.isnull().sum()[df_contacts.isnull().sum()>0].plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

```
SELECT c.Gender, COUNT(c.Gender) as cnt
FROM Contacts c
GROUP BY c.Gender 
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

[image]

Value counts are not same also. Why NULL value count for SQL is not correct?

Comment: `count(null-value)` returns 0. Do `count(*)`  to count null-values.

Comment: If you change `COUNT(c.Gender)` to `COUNT(*)` you'll likely get what you want/expect. The `COUNT` for a `NULL` value cannot be anything other than `0` in T-SQL, as `NULL` values are eliminated when aggregating.

Comment: Potential cross-site duplicate: [Why does COUNT() aggregate return 0 for 'NULL'?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/153586/why-does-count-aggregate-return-0-for-null)

Comment: In general, `NULL` does not act in SQL as it does in other languages, this includes comparison (`=`, `!=`), counting etc. When you translate conditions to SQL you always need to add `NULL` handling.